# How to get userid from eventlistener which are called from AJAX

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using symfony2 and FOSUserBundle.

Normally,I can get user data from Controller

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

or

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

But now,I want to get the userdata from eventlistner which are called from Ajax.

Is it possible? or not?

my source is here.

```
    namespace Acme\MemberBundle\EventListener;

    use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Event\CalendarEvent;
    use ADesigns\CalendarBundle\Entity\EventEntity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

    class CalendarEventListener
    {
        private $entityManager;

        public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        }

        public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent)
        {
            $startDate = $calendarEvent->getStartDatetime();
            $endDate = $calendarEvent->getEndDatetime();


           $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();//it doesnt work

            // load events using your custom logic here,
            // for instance, retrieving events from a repository

            $companyEvents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('UserBundle:MutorSche')
                    ->createQueryBuilder('company_events')
                    ->where('company_events.event_datetime BETWEEN :startDate and :endDate')
                    ->setParameter('startDate', $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                    ->setParameter('endDate', $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                    ->getQuery()->getResults();



            foreach($companyEvents as $companyEvent) {

                // create an event with a start/end time, or an all day event
                if ($companyEvent->getAllDayEvent() === false) {
                    $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), $companyEvent->getEndDatetime());
                } else {
                    $eventEntity = new EventEntity($companyEvent->getTitle(), $companyEvent->getStartDatetime(), null, true);
                }

                //optional calendar event settings
                $eventEntity->setAllDay(true); // default is false, set to true if this is an all day event
                $eventEntity->setBgColor('#FF0000'); //set the background color of the event's label
                $eventEntity->setFgColor('#FFFFFF'); //set the foreground color of the event's label
                $eventEntity->setUrl('http://www.google.com'); // url to send user to when event label is clicked
                $eventEntity->setCssClass('my-custom-class'); // a custom class you may want to apply to event labels

                //finally, add the event to the CalendarEvent for displaying on the calendar
                $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
            }
        }
    }
```

according to @nifr's advice.

I changed a bit in my source cord like

```
class CalendarEventListener
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $container;//add

    public function __construct(
            EntityManager $entityManager,
            ContainerInterface $container)//add
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->container = $container;//add
    }
```

then I want to pass the second argument to eventlistner.
I am using services.xml to make listener.
How can I add second argument on this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
      <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services">

        <services>
            <service id="acme.memberbundle.calendar_listener" class="Acme\MemberBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener">
                <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
                <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="calendar.load_events" method="loadEvents" />
            </service>

        </services>
      </container>
```

Comment: Accept the other solution (having most upvotes), as it is closer to the Symfony philosophy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject the container via [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html) into your listener class in order to acccess it.

Read more about it in the [book chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html).

```
your.listener:
    class: Acme\MemberBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener
    arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

Though injecting the whole container is performance-wise not the best idea among with some other reasons like testability ( you should normally only inject the services you need in your class instead of the container )...

...in your case if you aren't using a UserCallable you will get a circular reference when injecting `@security.context`.

So the quickest solution is injecting the container and adjusting your listener's constructor:

```
private $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}



public function someOtherMethod()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: THank you @nifr


I almost get it .in my case,I need to pass two arguments to event listener both entitymanager and container
So I changed the source and added to main article.Could you kindly check that please?

Comment: It's possible to add multiple arguments , just add another xml node `<argument type="service" id="container" />` but you don't need two arguments in your case ... you can get the entityManager from the container aswell ... `$this->entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')` in the constructor.

Comment: I see.@nifr  but '<argument type="service" id="container" />' says The service "acme.memberbundle.calendar_listener" has a dependency on a non-existent service "container".I almost get there...though..thanks for your support.

Comment: I think I should make another TOpic for this problem,the first problem is sloved by your help.thanks alot !

Comment: You should inject only the service that you need not the container.

Comment: is it good idea to put direct service container?? pass  security.token_storage instead container.

Answer (score 17):

As of Symfony 2.6 this issue should be fixed. A pull request has just been accepted into the master. Your problem is described in here.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11690

As of Symfony 2.6, you can inject the `security.token_storage` into your listener. This service will contain the token as used by the `SecurityContext` in <=2.5. In 3.0 this service will replace the `SecurityContext::getToken()` altogether. You can see a basic change list here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements#deprecated-the-security-context-service

Example usage in 2.6:

*Your configuration:*

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: EntityListener
        arguments:
            - "@security.token_storage"
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

*Your Listener*

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class EntityListener
{
    private $token_storage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token_storage)
    {
        $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifeCycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $entity->setCreatedBy($this->token_storage->getToken()->getUsername());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to not have the `Symfony profiler/toolbar` turned on. I don't know why, but that made `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()` return `null` every time.

In the file, `config_dev.yml` make sure the following is set:

```
web_profiler:
  toolbar: false
```

Comment: I hate it when my answers are voted down with no explanation as to why. This was a legitimate solution for me.