# Pass the 'container' as an argument to service

Tags: symfony

I am making services and want to pass 'container' as argument.
because I want to use like this

```
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

my Acme/MemberBundle/Resouces/confit/services.xml is like this below.

```
<services>
    <service id="acme.memberbundle.calendar_listener" class="Acme\MemberBundle\EventListener\CalendarEventListener">
        <argument type="service" id="container" />
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="calendar.load_events" method="loadEvents" />
    </service>

</services>
```

but it says 
'The service "acme.memberbundle.calendar_listener" has a dependency on a non-existent service "container"'.

How can I pass my container to services?

this problem is related [How to get userid from eventlistener which are called from AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020733/how-to-get-userid-from-eventlistener-which-are-called-from-ajax)

Comment: The name of the service is not `container`, it's `service_container`. I have fixed the answer from your original question. PS: I would recommend injecting the `security.context` directly instead of injecting the whole container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The container is registered as the service called "service_container", so you must pass "service_container" and not just "container":

```
<argument type="service" id="service_container" />
```

This is why currently Symfony doesn't understand what is the service "container" because there is no one registered with this name !

Comment: it works.thanks for your good advice. I am not sure where 'id' I can find,but I will keep study.

Comment: You can list all registered services by executing this command: php app/console container:debug ;)